# Filtering special characters in login in mvc asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

Hey guys I am trying to to make my login secure against sql injections.  I want to filter the special characters out using something like preg_replace in php.  Any advice on how I could apply this to the input in asp.net?

Here is my login in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Login(Models.User user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                if (isValid(user.UserName, user.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(db.User.Where(u => u.UserName == user.UserName).FirstOrDefault().UserRole.Name, false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Clock", "User");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "User Name or Password is incorrect");
                }
            }

            return View(user);
        }
```

This is my isValid:

```
private bool isValid(string UserName, string Password)
        {
            bool isValid = false;

            var user = db.User.Where(u => u.UserName == UserName).FirstOrDefault();
            if (user != null)
            {
                if(Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(user.Password, Password))
                {  
                    isValid = true;
                }
            }

            return isValid;
        }
```

And this is my login.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login Failed.  Check your login details.");
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Login Form</legend>
            <div>@Html.LabelFor(u=>u.UserName)</div>
            <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.UserName)
            </div>

            <div>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.Password)</div>
            <div>
                @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Password)
        </div>
            <input type="Submit" value="Log In" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're calling the database twice to get that user. Why not do something like `IsValid(...out User user)`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using some kind of an ORM for your data access. This in itself should take care of any Sql Injection issues, most likely by using properties, so you don't need to worry about it. Just make sure that when you render any user entered content you're html/url encoding it. Most elements will do it for you by default.

Comment: Roger, ya it did it by itself. It sent me toA potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (UserName="*&#$%@*#*$") and didnt process.  Is there somewhere in the web.config file where I can reroute this to another view?

Comment: @Shawn that's a separate issue. It's request validation and it's possible to slip sql injection by that. You can handle it using regular global error handling methods or turn it off.

Comment: If you want to allow any characters you can either use the AllowHtml attribute on the properties of your ViewModel or you can use the ValidateFilter action filter on the action, controller, or register it globally. If you take the latter approach just make sure you're encoding anything you echo back to a page. Razor will do this for you by default when you use "@" to output values, but if you're using @Html.Raw anywhere you'll need to be careful.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, ASP.NET uses Entity Framework as its ORM. If that's the case, they already take care of SQL injection for you, see this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716760.aspx

Quoting:

LINQ to Entities injection attacks:

Although query composition is possible in LINQ to Entities, it is performed through the object model API. Unlike Entity SQL queries, LINQ to Entities queries are not composed by using string manipulation or concatenation, and they are not susceptible to traditional SQL injection attacks.